# Ionic: How to uglify and minify my code before release?

Tags: ionic-framework, minify

I am getting ready to release my first app build in ionic. I am interested in how I can minify and uglify my code? Are there any plugins for that?

Thanks
uksz

Answer (score 2):

Running `ionic build --prod` did the trick for me.  I am using ionic to deploy my app as a website.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ionic cordova build <platform> --prod --release` will create you a release version of the app with the code uglyfied and minified.

Also running a simple `ionic cordova build <platform>` will also do the job. The minified and uglyfied js is located on the `www` folder as `main.js`

Take in count that what minifies and uglyfies the source code is `ionic-app-scripts`.

Comment: What versions of Ionic is this good for?  My app is still on Ionic v1.  I have tried cordova-minify and cordova-uglify - but in both cases my js files return as "undefined"

Comment: This still works for Ionic v1, the scripts get automatically minified and uglyfied, just use the "ionic cordova build" command.

Comment: not certain this is accurate. I just tried `ionic build ios` and checked the files in the ../platforms/ios/www folder and all the files are still the same.  In ionic v1 there is no `ionic cordova build ios`, its just `ionic build ios`.  I am on Ionic CLI v1.7.16

Answer (score 1):

There is an automated task runner for JavaScript called Gulp ( [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com) ). It has packages like:

- gulp-minify-css and gulp-uglify

Hope it helps.