# How to minify ionic 3 app for desktop browser use

Tags: ionic-framework, minify

when call "ionic serve", related html and javascript files are located in "www" folder. i can use the folder to deploy in webserver.

But the javascript files are not minified or uglified. Could anyone help me out, how can i minify them through ionic script or something?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674158/ionic-how-to-uglify-and-minify-my-code-before-release/